# In Dialogflow reason for error message: "Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.setIamPolicy' denied on resource dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es, sendmail, chatbot

I was trying webhook to send email in chatbot (dialogflow). Getting following error (log entry) .
What may be the reson?

message: "***Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.setIamPolicy' denied on resource 'projects/rare-shadow-276706/locations/us-central1/functions/dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment' (or resource may not exist).***"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved
After setting Project Owner role,  no error.

Thanks

Comment: my pleasure @Radhakrishna. GCP service accounts can get pretty confusing with respect to access control and authentication. Owning your projects eliminates many of these nuanced issues.

Answer (score 4):

#### The issue

This is an issue with the proper permissions, and the service account permissions. What's happening is the `dialogflowFirebaseFunction` needs to have the `setIamPolict` role.

#### The fix

You can achieve this when you (the user) have the `roles/iam.securityAdmin` role. [Check this out](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#iam-roles) for more info. Other roles may also work, but this role will suffice. I would suggest also deleting the existing cloud function, get the new role, and then create the cloud function again.

Comment: ...if you are not the owner of your project you are working on